# Pip not working with python 2.7.3 on windows vista

Tags: python, pip, typeerror

Here's my log file:

```
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win32-2.7

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto

copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto

copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\py21compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random

copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random

copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random

copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna

copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna

copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna

copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna

copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature

copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protocol

copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protocol

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Signature

copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Signature

copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Signature

copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Signature

running build_ext

building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension

warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_admin\pycrypto\setup.py", line 456, in <module>

    core.setup(**kw)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 53, in run

    return _install.run(self)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_admin\pycrypto\setup.py", line 253, in run

    build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_admin\pycrypto\setup.py", line 150, in build_extensions

    build_ext.build_extensions(self)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions

    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension

    depends=ext.depends)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 266, in query_vcvarsall

    vcvarsall = find_vcvarsall(version)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 243, in find_vcvarsall

    toolskey = "VS100COMNTOOLS" % version

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_admin...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_admin\\pycrypto\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip-mrsuuh-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_admin\pycrypto
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_admin\\pycrypto\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip-mrsuuh-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_admin\pycrypto
```

I am unable to pip down any files at all, I've spent hours searching, and am still unable to resolve this issue. Can anybody please help me?

Any explanation to my problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I found that I need to have a linux based operating system for this to work anyways...